# i want normal query to codeigniter query

Tags: codeigniter

```
   $this->db->select('movie_details.movie_id','movie_details.title','movie_details.producer','movie_details.director'.'movie_details.writer','GROUP_CONCAT(movie_genre.genre) As genre','movie_genre.movie_id');
          $this->db->from('movie_details');
          $this->db->join('movie_genre','movie_genre.movie_id=movie_details.movie_id');

            $result=$this->db->get();
            return $result->result_array();
```

I give one query in normal mysql. but i want this query in codeigniter form because i want to learn codeigniter.

```
 $query="select movie_details.movie_id,movie_details.title,movie_details.producer,movie_details.director,movie_details.writer,
        GROUP_CONCAT(movie_genre.genre) As genre ,
        movie_genre.movie_id
        FROM
        movie_details,
        movie_genre
        WHERE
        movie_genre.movie_id=movie_details.movie_id
        GROUP BY
        movie_genre.movie_id limit 110,15";
```

Comment: yor are right but i face problem in this query so i ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('movie_details.movie_id','movie_details.title','movie_details.producer','movie_details.director'.'movie_details.writer','GROUP_CONCAT(movie_genre.genre) As genre','movie_genre.movie_id');
//This is not right way to CI select.It will select only movie_id
```

use this

```
$this->db->select('movie_details.movie_id , movie_details.title , movie_details.producer , movie_details.director , movie_details.writer , GROUP_CONCAT(movie_genre.genre)  genre , movie_genre.movie_id');
```